# TextView MeasuredHeight is not properly calculated when Android RecyclerView scrolls

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging-library, android-binding-adapter, android-pagedlistview

Probably this is the most common question regarding Android RecyclerView in stackoverflow and yet I could not find any suitable solution anywhere which fulfils my requirement.

### My Problem

I am using Paging Library with Room Database and Retrofit to populate contents in a Recyclerview.There are two VIEW_TYPE; One is the actual data in a cardview and another is a progressbar layout which shows up at bottom of Recyclerview when API is called to fetch next set of data. Each card view in the list is fairly complex holding image and texts.

Everything works fine till I start scroll up when contents get messed up. To be precise, one textview needs to be displayed based on another textView’s measured height. And the measured height is not coming properly after I scroll down and up. Image Screenshot attached below

There are 2 solutions I have found almost everyone suggested.

1. **override getItemViewType(int position) in the adapter and return the position**

   ~ I can't use this solution as I have to keep 2 VIEW_TYPES. My getItemViewType code is as below :

   `public int getItemViewType(int position) {
           if (hasExtraRow() && position == getItemCount() - 1) {
               return R.layout.item_network_state;
           } else {
               return R.layout.card_post_timeline;
           }
       }`
2. Use **setIsRecyclable(false)** in ViewHolder

~ If I use this solution it solves my problem but I don't want to use this as this defeats the whole purpose of Recyclerview and it will badly affect performance when there will be large data set.

### My Code

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        if (viewType == R.layout.card_post_timeline) {
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_post_timeline, parent, false);
            TimelinePostViewHolder viewHolder = new TimelinePostViewHolder(view, context,optionsSelected );
            return viewHolder;
        } else if (viewType == R.layout.item_network_state) {
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_network_state, parent, false);
            return new NetworkStateItemViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown view type");
        }
    }

public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case R.layout.card_post_timeline:
                ((TimelinePostViewHolder) holder).bindTo(getItem(position)); // Data binding happens here
                break;
            case R.layout.item_network_state:
                ((NetworkStateItemViewHolder) holder).bindView(networkState);
                break;
        }
    }`
```

### Question

What's the alternative we can use to resolve this age-old Recyclerview problem ?

### Updated --

Only problem is that "Show More" textview visibility which is getting calculated by postBody textview measured height . After scrolling down and then up, measured height of Textview always coming same irrespective of the text content.

Logic for the same as below:

```
private void renderPostContent(Post post) {
        tvPostBody.fromHtml(post.getPostContent());
        Log.d(StringConstants.LOG_TAG, tvPostBody.getText().toString());
        int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(IntegerConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        tvPostBody.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int measuredTextViewHeight = tvPostBody.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.d(StringConstants.LOG_TAG, "list position - " + getAdapterPosition() + " measuredHeight - " + measuredTextViewHeight);
        if (measuredTextViewHeight > IntegerConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH) {
            tvPostBody.setMaxHeight(IntegerConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH);
            tvShowMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // setIsRecyclable(false);
            Log.d(StringConstants.LOG_TAG, "ShowMore visibile");
        } else {
            tvPostBody.setMaxHeight(IntegerConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH);
            tvShowMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //setIsRecyclable(true);
            Log.d(StringConstants.LOG_TAG, "ShowMore gone");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also post onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder and the ViewHolder classes you have? My intuition is that there should be 2 VIEW_TYPEs, 2 ViewHolder classes, so that the loading progress bar doesn't get recycled for actual content.

Comment: Edited the question and onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder given. Yes I have 2 View Holder classes. But they are too long to be given here..

Comment: i didn't read all of  your post but normally in a recyclerview if someone is having problems like yours, they are only setting properties sometimes.   When that happens, you can get holdover values from previous recycled views.  Let's say sometimes you make a button visible.  You must also set it invisible on everything else.  This also applies to heights, colors, fonts, texts, etc.  You haven't lived until you've typed into an edittext and seen it appear in another one.

Comment: Hi John, I also think same but if you can see the Updated Section in my post( I have given the code), I am setting visibility of ShowMore Button( tvShowMore) in if-else case both. But my problem is visibility of that depends on the textview measured height and that height is not coming properly after scrolling.

Comment: It seems  setIsRecyclable(false) is the only way to solve this, nothing else worked. This is so frustrating !!